# Show a loading image while populating list of Combo Box

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a dialog box which contains a Dojo ComboBox. Now I make a call to the database to get data to populate the Combo Box. I want to display a "loading image" during this time. How to do this?

Comment: You'll need to show some code before you at any help :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to get a loading overlay using the dojo toolkit, in this case the official tutorial should suffice.

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/recipes/loading_overlay/

A previous question can also help you regarding the same

[Dojo "loading"-message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487174/dojo-loading-message)

Answer (score 0):

The answers to the question linked by @AurA specifies a number of techniques to accomplish what you are trying to do.

[Dojo "loading"-message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487174/dojo-loading-message)

I use the StandBy widget.  Here is a fiddle that demonstrates it's use.

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/253Te/

```
    var standby = new Standby({
          id: "standbyObj",
          target: "standby",
          color: "transparent",
          zindex: "auto",
          duration: "1000"
    });
    dojo.body().appendChild(standby.domNode);
    standby.startup();

    on(dojo.byId('btn'), 'click', function() {
        standby.show();

        // simulate a request.  hide the timeout in 5 seconds
        setTimeout(function() {
            standby.hide(); 
        }, 5000);
    });
```

Comment: Instead of timeout, what kind of event of the ComboBox that will trigger when it is completed in populating it?  Could the onSearch  be the trigger event?

Comment: Instead of timeout, what kind of event of the ComboBox that will trigger when it is completed in populating it?  Could the onSearch  be the trigger event? Can the target property applied to body tag or html tag?